# How to use the result of std::regex_search?

Tags: c++, regex, string, clr

I'm simply calling

```
std::smatch m;
if (std::regex_search 
  (std::string (strT.GetString ()), 
  m,
  std::regex ("((\\d[\\s_\\-.]*){10,13})")))
{
  ...
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to extract the matched values from m.

EVERY SINGLE page on the subject writes it to cout which is worthless to me. I just want to get what's been captured in a string, but no matter what I try it crashes with a "string iterators incompatible" error message.

OK so I tried a few more things and got annoyed at a lot more, most notably about how the same code worked in online testers but not on my computer. I've come down to this

```
std::string s (strT.GetString ()) ;
std::smatch m;
if (std::regex_search (
    s, 
    m,
    std::regex ("((\\d[\\s_\\-.]*){10,13})")))
{
    std::string v = m[ 0 ] ;
}
```

working, but this

```
std::smatch m;
if (std::regex_search (
    std::string (strT.GetString ()), 
    m,
    std::regex ("((\\d[\\s_\\-.]*){10,13})")))
{
    std::string v = m[ 0 ] ;
}
```

Not Working For Some Reason (with the incompatible string iterator error thingy).
There's surely some trick to it. I'll let someone who knows explain it.

Comment: do you just want to know if string matches the regex or do you want to search items using a regex?

Comment: Use `sregex_token_iterator` or `sregex_iterator`. Fix your regex, too, but that is not the current issue.

Comment: My pattern captures exactly what I need, thank you very much. What I don't get is how I can 'read' my captures in the `std::smatch m;` var.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Seems likely. Can you write it in an answer so I'll accept it? Also would it work by placing a `GetBuffer()` instead of the `GetString()` ? While I can see the necessity I don't like using an entire variable for a single line.

Comment: Yeah I've decided that wasn't a useful dupe. Re-opened and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that you can just assign the match to a `std::string`; you don't *have* to use the stream insertion feature.

However, your third example crashes because `std::smatch` holds references/handles to positions in the original source data … which in your crashy case is the temporary `strT.GetString()` that went out of scope as soon as the regex was done (read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results)).

Your second example is correct.

I concede that the C++ regex implementation is not entirely intuitive at first glance.